# Mathematical functions in lavaan's lavTestWald function

Tags: r

I'm using the `lavaan` package in `R` and want to use `lavaan::lavTestWald` to test the fit of a model under linear constraints. This test is part of a loop, so there are a large number of models where I want to test these constraints.

As part of the test, I want to set the *absolute value* of two quantities to be equal. Is there a way to do this? I know about R's `abs()` function but haven't been able to figure out how to incorporate `abs()` into `lavaan::lavTestWald`.

Here's a reproducible example.

```
HS.model <- ' visual  =~ x1 + a*x2 + b*x3
              textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
              speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9'

fit <- cfa(HS.model, data = HolzingerSwineford1939)
lavTestWald(fit, "abs(a) == abs(b)") # I want something like this
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but the reason that your code is not working as expected seems related to `abs()`. This worked for me:

```r
lavTestWald(fit, "sqrt(a^2) == sqrt(b^2)")
```

Note that you could also define new parameters in your model statement and test those, but I don't know if that makes any difference in your situation.

```r
HS.model <- ' visual  =~ x1 + a*x2 + b*x3
              textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
              speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9
# new1 := abs(a) - abs(b)
new2 := sqrt(a^2) - sqrt(b^2)
'
fit <- cfa(HS.model, data = HolzingerSwineford1939)
lavTestWald(fit, "new2 == 0")
```